# How does one set input-decode-map on GUI frames in emacsclient?

Tags: key-bindings, gui-emacs

I'm trying to adjust bindings in `input-decode-map` (to distinguish C-m and RET in GUI mode).  None of the advice given on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212696/emacs-input-decode-map-for-terminal), [gnu.emacs.help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/ZGu2MNkJGrI), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4wnfnb/inputdecodemap_doesnt_work_for_terminal/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/537922/how-do-i-get-my-emacs-init-files-to-load-correctly-with-emacs-server) seems to work.  I ended up with this:

```
(defun ~/setup-C-m (&rest args)
  (define-key input-decode-map [?\C-m] [C-m]))

(~/setup-C-m)
(add-hook 'tty-setup-hook #'~/setup-C-m)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'~/setup-C-m)
(add-hook 'terminal-init-xterm-hook #'~/setup-C-m)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'~/setup-C-m)
```

Even with all these, starting Emacs with `emacsclient --alternate-editor="" --create-frame --frame-parameters="((fullscreen . maximized))"` results in `input-decode-map` being set to this:

```
Value:
(keymap
 (27 keymap
     (C-backspace)
     (C-delete))
 (C-M-backspace)
 (C-M-delete)
 (M-backspace)
 (M-delete))
```

Which doesn't include the `C-m` binding.  I've printed the value of `input-decode-map` when my `setup-C-m` function is called, and it's always an empty keymap.

How can I ensure that my `setup-C-m` function runs every time I create a frame and properly sets `input-decode-map`?

Comment: That's quite some bizarre prefix you've got here.  The code in your example won't work because you haven't defined such a function.

Comment: Yup, of course, sorry for the typo.  The question stands, of course.

Comment: I use `~/` as a prefix for all my personal functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `after-make-frame-functions` isn't working because you're ignoring the `FRAME` argument, and therefore not operating on the new frame at all.

Your function needs to do this:

```el
(with-selected-frame FRAME
  ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook #'~/setup-C-m)` should do what you want (at least since 27.1).